# How to connect to SQL Server database from Access over the internet or TCP/IP?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have setup my SQL Server so that it can be accessed via TCP/IP. I know that my setup is working properly because I can use any computer on the internet to access the SQL Server using SQL Server Management studio.

Looking at various forums online I came up with this connection string:

```
Data Source='57.121.2.12,1433';Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog='MY_DB';User ID='MY_DB_USER';Password='MY_DB_PASSWORD';
```

But when I try to connect using this connection string I get:

> Could not find installable ISAM.

I am not sure if that is the correct connection string to connect to SQL Server over the internet but I cannot find any other connection string anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten that error message when my connection string wasn't just right. Maybe the network part of the string is getting you?

> When connecting through the SQLOLEDB provider use the syntax "Network Library=dbmssocn" and when connecting through the MSDASQL provider use the syntax "Network=dbmssocn".

Link: https://www.connectionstrings.com/define-sql-server-network-protocol/